# How to get the ajax response in the appropriate charset?

Tags: jquery, ajax, encoding, character-encoding

I have to write a jquery function that gets a webpage and then shows it in a div.

```
                 $.ajax({
                   beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                       xhr.overrideMimeType("text/html; charset="+document.characterSet);
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/html; charset="+document.characterSet);
                   },
                   CcntentType:"text/html; charset="+document.characterSet,
                   type: "GET",
                   url: destination,
                   statusCode: {
                    200: function( response){
                          callback(response);
                    }
                   },
                   error: function() {
                    // default behavior                           

                   }
                 });
```

BUT when I insert the received data in the html I get some funny symbols - rectanges and ?.

The page in which I do the ajax request has meta tag. 
I do not have access to the page, to which Im doing the ajax request, so I can't change it.

The charset is windows-1251 and that that only happens in IE10, in firefox and chrome everything is ok.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to change the charset of your own page to the same as the page you're calling.